# randomly place Strings from a list into a 2D array character by character

Tags: java, arrays, list, loops, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to randomly place each of the words from the puzzleWords or userSpecifiedWords list into the puzzle 2D array. The words can be able to be placed up to down vertical, down to up vertical, left to right horizontal, and right to left horizontal. Essentially making a word search. But can't seem to figure out how to place the next character in the correct position so it satisfies those requirements.

I've tried to initially generate a random position in the 2d array, then placing the first character of the first word into that position but struggle with the placement of the next character, then moving on to the next word.

```
//Initialising the 2d array and list of words.

public class WordSearchPuzzle {
    private char [][] puzzle;
    private List<String> puzzleWords;

//What I have so far to take the word out of the array, generate a random pos in 2d array then check if the pos is empty, if empty place the first char of word in that pos else generate new pos.

for (int i = 0; i < puzzleWords.size(); i++) {
            for (int r = 0; r < puzzle.length; r++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < puzzle[r].length; c++) {
                    String s = puzzleWords.get(i);
                    int wordLength = s.length();
                    char firstChar = s.charAt(0);
                    while(puzzle[rowGenerate][colGenerate] != ' ') {
                        puzzle[rowGenerate][colGenerate] = puzzle[(int) Math.random() * gridSize + 1][(int) Math.random() * gridSize + 1];
                    }
                    puzzle[rowGenerate][colGenerate] = firstChar;
                }
```

Comment: You have 3 `for` loops and one `while` loop, you need to re-think what you want to do and come up with a simpler design. You should first decide in what direction you want to write a word and a get a starting position and then make sure the word fit, otherwise use another direction and/or starting position. Once that is done it should be quite easy to place the word in the 2d array, then of course "easy" might not be correct depending on what rules you have for placing the words but I didn't really get that from your description.

Comment: The words can be placed anywhere within the 2d array as long as there is space and that it doesn't replace an existing word. I've recently thought of introducing a switch in terms of what direction to use. Would this be a good implementation?